# SDL - Inconsistent SDL_RWops issue on iOS

Tags: ios, c, io, sdl

I'm developing a game for Android and iOS in C using SDL. I've completed the Android version, and I'm now porting it to iOS. In order to save game data, I'm writing a binary file to the directory returned by SDL_GetPrefPath. This has worked flawlessly on Android, but has had mixed results on iOS devices. I say "devices" because it only seems to be a problem when deployed to my iPhone 5s, and not on the iOS Simulator.

The save data is read when the game starts.

```
prefPath = strcat(SDL_GetPrefPath("<org>", "<app>"), "save.bin");
SDL_RWops* rw = SDL_RWFromFile(prefPath, "rb");
if (rw != NULL)
{
    ...
    SDL_RWread(rw, ...);
    ...
    SDL_RWclose(rw);
}
```

Most of the time, this works as it should, but sometimes I get this error in the output window.

```
DEBUG: Error reading from datastream
```

The error displayed when writing to the file fails is more elaborate, but only marginally more helpful.

```
DEBUG: Couldn't open /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<GUID>/Library/
Application Support/<org>/<app>/save.bin
```

To make matters worse, sometimes when I run the game and these messages don't appear, all updates to the save data are inexplicably lost in the next run.

What I want to know is whether or not this method of saving my game is even appropriate for iOS. Should I switch to a more platform-specific method of saving data that is guaranteed to work, or is there some fundamental misunderstanding at play here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `strcat` is very likely to stomp memory, so if it works in some cases - it is pure luck. After that, nothing should come as a surprise. Create buffer and strncat (or snprintf) to it. Also you need to `SDL_free` result of `SDL_GetPrefPath` after you done using it (but that's memory leak, not crash).

Comment: Seems to be working so far, thanks! What's the problem with strcat exactly?

Comment: `SDL_GetPrefPath` allocated memory with `SDL_alloc` and put resulting path there. This memory is now your responsibility (you have to release it with `SDL_free` when no longer needed), but buffer size is only enough to hold what SDL have put there. With `strcat` you're writing some extra to this buffer, which it very likely don't have space for - overwriting something else that (probably) was placed afterwards. It's the same as `malloc(1)` but writing much more to it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I guess it's good practice not to mix SDL's memory allocation functions with the standard ones.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, strcat never allocates memory, it just assumes that there would be enough and things go very bad if it isn't the case.

Comment: That's even worse! I'll just avoid it altogether from now on.